# Internal Server Error for Hello World django project in production

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I have my apache server directing traffic from `mysite.com/home` to my wsgi.py file, but when  `get_wsgi_application()` is called I get an internal server error.

Running apache2 on amazon linux EC2. In wsgi.py, I've replaced the line,

`application = get_wsgi_application()`

with the function,

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'sys.path = %s\n' % repr(sys.path).encode('UTF-8')
    output += b'sys.version = %s\n' % repr(sys.version).encode('UTF-8')
    output += b'sys.prefix = %s\n' % repr(sys.prefix).encode('UTF-8')


    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

and the server error goes away. It shows that apache is using the correct python version (3.7) and doesn't return an error when I `import get_wsgi_application()` from `django.core.wsgi`. To my understanding this means apache is finding the access point to my django project just fine, and it has permission to look into the file and show its contents. What am I missing?

Other possibly relevant information I can think of:
user "apache" and group "apache" own the outer mysite directory and everything in it. I've set all the settings in settings.py for production according to the django deployment checklist. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/wsgi/django')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/wsgi/django/mysite')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    Redirect permanent / httpswww.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName httpswww.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com
    ServerAdmin person@gmail.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/efs/Website"

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite

    WSGIScriptAlias /home /usr/local/wsgi/django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

    <Directory "/usr/local/wsgi/django/mysite/mysite">
    <Files "wsgi.py">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/crt/path.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/key/path.key"

</VirtualHost>
```

settings.py:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'string_I_havent_moved_yet'

DEBUG= False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.mysite.com', e2-serial-numbers.compute-1.amazonaws.com']
```

Comment: Can you set `DEBUG=True` in settings.py and post error here?

Comment: Where do I find the error log? Here is the line from /var/log/httpd/access_log 
04.132.114.64 - - [17/Jan/2019:17:45:00 +0000] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 500 536 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"